# 405 Not Allowed for Ajax Contact Form code

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm fairly new to programming in general, but I am trying to create an ajax contact form. I've have tried numerous different methods but none of them seem to be working effectively. My code is as follows:

html/js code:

```html
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <form class="form--square form-email" id="contactformid" method="post" name="contactformid">
                        <h4 class="text-center">Or you can reach us right here:</h4>
                        <div class="input-with-icon col-sm-12">
                            <i class="icon-Business-Man" style="color:#0aaf4b"></i> <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required="" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-with-icon col-sm-6">
                            <i class="icon-Email" style="color:#0aaf4b"></i> <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required="" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-with-icon col-sm-6">
                            <i class="icon-Smartphone-3" style="color:#0aaf4b"></i> <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required="" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" required="" rows="8"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button class="btn btn--primary vpe" id="submitBtn" name="submit" style="width: 100%" type="submit">SEND</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="feedback"></div>
                    </form>
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
                    </script> 
                    <script>
                                     $(document).ready(function(){

                                         $( "#submitBtn" ).click(function( event ) {
                                             //values
                                             var name=$('#name').val():
                                             var email=$('#email').val():
                                             var phone=$('#phone').val():
                                             var message=$('#message').val():
                                             var dataString = {"name": name, "email":email, "phone": phone, "message":message}
                                             console.log(dataString);

                                             $.ajax({
                                                 type:"POST",
                                                 url:"./newest.php",
                                                 data: dataString,
                                                 success: function() {
                                                     alert("Email Sent Successfully");
                                                 }
                                             });
                                         });
                                     });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my php code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'],$_POST['message'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $from = 'Contact Us Page'; 
 $to = 'redwards@farmdrive.co.ke'; 
 $subject = 'Message from Contact Us ';
 
 $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

 // Check if name has been entered
 if (!$_POST['name']) {
  $errName = 'Please enter your name';
 }
 
 // Check if email has been entered and is valid
 if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
 }
 if (!$_POST['phone']) {
  $errEmail = 'Please enter your telephone number';
 }
 //Check if message has been entered
 if (!$_POST['message']) {
  $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
 }
 
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
  $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We will be in touch</div>';
 } else {
  $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
 }
}
 }
?>
```

As of now I am receiving a '405 Not Allowed'. Please let me know if you have any advice or suggestions.

Comment: Can you please tell me the location of "newest.php" and your form file?

Comment: Both the newest.php file and the html file (contact.tpl.html) are in the folder: mywebsite/src/app/contact/tpls

Comment: Try to change  url:"./newest.php", to  url:"newest.php",